# How to extract limonene from the orange peels?

Tags: experimental-chemistry, food-chemistry

What is a reasonable procedure to extract the orange essential oil from the rinds?  I thought this would be a common experiment.

Here's what [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orange_oil) had to say, they  identify the essential oil as mostly [D-limonene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limonene) (it's an isomer):

> Orange oil is an essential oil produced by cells within the rind of an orange fruit (Citrus sinensis fruit). In contrast to most essential oils, it is extracted as a by-product of orange juice production by centrifugation, producing a cold-pressed oil. It is composed of mostly (greater than 90%) d-limonene, and is often used in place of pure d-limonene. D-limonene can be extracted from the oil by distillation.

A centrifuge seems to be more involved than I'd like, since these are just household objects.  I considered for example boiling the water with orange rinds in it (as would be the recipe) except maybe something evaporates into the air.  Should I consider using a different solvent? [Wikihow](https://www.wikihow.com/Extract-Oil-from-Orange-Peels) suggested I use vodka or olive oil. There's also a video on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IC0qYhQ2XNg) for extracting lemon oil.  It doesn't look so elementary.

Comment: Can you handle steam distillation?  https://edu.rsc.org/download?ac=12160